# What is annotation to override transaction timeout?

Tags: jakarta-ee, annotations, weblogic

New to EE - trying to reconfigure Weblogic's default timeout of 30 seconds without having to write up a weblogic-ejb-jar.xml file. I've used only annotations now but the only thing that I have seen is in the DD here:

`<transaction-descriptor>`
`<trans-timeout-seconds>1200</trans-timeout-seconds>`
`</transaction-descriptor>`

Anyway to avoid have a descriptor file just for this?

Comment: Is simply changing it in the admin console not an option?

Comment: @better_use_mkstemp - In the console in the JTA tab I only saw the ability to change the timeout for the entire domain. I'm looking to edit the transaction length of one EJB module.

Comment: If you are working with JMS you can create your own connection factory and then configure the transaction timeout like: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs100/ConsoleHelp/pagehelp/JMSjmsconnectionjmsconnectionfactoryconfigtransactionparamstitle.html But that might not be exactly what you need

Comment: @better_use_mkstemp That's a great idea. It's not exactly what I had in mind but it could work. I could make a connection factory for that EJB. I just have to figure out which solution would be more complicated to deliver upon deployment. Thanks!

Comment: Cool - if you figure something out feel free to post the solution as answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I feel weird answering my own question but someone at work found this annotation.

`@ weblogic.javaee.TransactionTimeoutSeconds(1200)`

It is Weblogic specific but in my case, it will do. For anyone else who needs it, here is the link: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24972/annotations.htm#i1438354

Comment: You should'nt feel weird for that. Take a look a this [http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).