# How to run a long running process in JSF without facing "Connection Failed" error in browser

Tags: jsf, long-running-processes

I have a process which takes more than five minutes, after those minutes internet explorer throws a "Connection Failed" error, but internally it keeps running, the view throws the error. I increased the lifetime of the managed bean as shown:

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance (). GetExternalContext (). SetSessionMaxInactiveInterval (1440);
```

Keep sending the "Connection Failed" error

I added to the EJB methods the annotation of:

EDIT:

```
@TransactionAttribute (TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED)
```

the same problem...

I added to the web.xml:

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout> -1 </ session-timeout>
</ session-config>
```

the same problem...

my question is if at the code level can I eliminate that restriction that "the life cycle", or is it a time that has it inserted inside the server?

I work with:
- Jdeveloper 12.2.1 (Trinidad Framework)
- Oracle DB 10g
EDIT:
- Server Weblogic 12c

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18085304/what-is-annotation-to-override-transaction-timeout see if it helps

Comment: Thanks you but not working...

Comment: Do long work asynchronous... !!!